# Concurrent readers-writers behaving in an unexpected way

Tags: java, multithreading, file, concurrency, monitor

I am trying to make a program that runs several parallel readers and writers. I start some threads in a loop using `ExecutorService` class, the `run()` method of the Writer class just call two methods `StartWrite()`and `EndWrite()` and for the Reader class, `StartRead()` and `EndRead()`. These methods are wrapped in a monitor.

Here's the monitor:

```
public class RWMonitorAN {
  static int readers = 0;     
  static boolean writing = false;
  public static RandomAccessFile f;
  public static int n = 0;
  private final ReentrantLock mylock = new ReentrantLock();
  private final Condition toWrite = mylock.newCondition();
  private final Condition toRead = mylock.newCondition();

  public RWMonitorAN()
  {
    try { f = new RandomAccessFile("datos.dat", "rw"); } catch (IOException e) {}
  }

  void StartRead() {
    mylock.lock();
    try
    {
        if (writing)
            try {
                 toRead.wait();
                 toWrite.wait();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        readers++;

        try
        {   
            f.seek(0);
            while (f.getFilePointer()<f.length())
                System.out.print(f.readInt()+" ");
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    finally { mylock.unlock(); }
  }

  void EndRead() {
    mylock.lock();
    try
    {
        readers--;
        if (readers == 0) 
            toWrite.signal();
    }
    finally { mylock.unlock(); }
  }

  void StartWrite() {
    mylock.lock();
    try
    {
        if (writing || readers != 0)
          try {
             toWrite.wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        writing = true;

        try 
        { 
          f.writeInt(n); 
        } catch(IOException e) {}

        n++;
    }
    finally { mylock.unlock(); }
  }

  void EndWrite() {
    mylock.lock();
    try
    {
        writing = false;

        toWrite.signal();
    toRead.signal();
    }
    finally { mylock.unlock(); }
  }
```

But there's a problem: the program ends before the expected number of data is written and read. For example, if I start 20 writer and 20 reader threads, I expect 20 numbers to be written and read, but only 10~ are. If I run the program again (datos.dat would be already created) it keeps writing and reading and then 20 numbers are written.

Test:

**1st run**

- Written in the last executed thread: 0 1 2 3 4
- Read in the last executed thread: 0 1 2 3 4

**2nd run**

- Written in the last executed thread: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
- Read in the last executed thread: 0 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

What's wrong? How can I make it work properly?

**EDIT:** I tried printing the number of readers every time a reader finishes reading and the same number of readers is being printed several times. Shouldn't this **not** be happening? `readers--` is executed in a lock protected section of the code.

Comment: Can you ensure this is actually running, `toWrite.wait()` and `toRead.wait()` will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException` here, unless there is more code you are not showing us.

Comment: Check my answer's end, about your edit.

Comment: You're right, those exceptions are thrown, I was catching the wrong kind of exception so it seemed like none was thrown.

Comment: @dabadaba The two things I'd recommend are 1. Use `await` and not `wait` 2.  Have it sit in a `while(writing || reading)`  instead of if

Comment: I thought when using class Condition whiles needn't be used, and ifs worked just as fine but more efficiently.

Comment: That is not true, while is still needed for missed conditions.  For instance,  you have 2 threads on `await`.  Another thread `signalAll` after setting `writing = false` one thread wins and sees writing false and continues (later setting writing to true).  When done the other thread that was signaled now breaks out of the if (since not in a while) even though writing is true.  Missed conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching your exceptions everywhere and not reporting them anywhere nor do anything else to serve them. The first thing to "make it work properly" would probably be to check if there are exceptions called. For example, if you use more than one iterators on one data structure in Java it will probably throw concurrentModificationException at the start, to prevent unexpected behaviour in the future.

What is the point of using multiple readers from a file if, as it appears, you set every new one to the very beginning of a file with seek(0)? And your reader appears to try to read the whole file

```
 while (f.getFilePointer()<f.length())
                    System.out.print(f.readInt()+" ");
```

and your writer tries to read a single int in

`f.writeInt(n);`

so if you started n threads I would not expect n numbers to be read.

Finally, have you considered what happens when you start another writer/reader after startRead unlocked mylock but before EndRead locked it again? Why not to put the logic from EndRead just at the end of startRead method then?

Comment: Actually in my program I do report them, I deleted it here so the code didn't look much long. And no exception is reported.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't make much sense, but if I delete that line no data is read.

Comment: How do you call your methods from the monitor? I mean what is the code supposed to start and run all this? Do you just go in a loop call startWrite, stopWrite, startRead, stopRead?

Comment: I run Writer and Reader objects in a loop in the main thread, their run methods just run the monitor's methods. Obviously the monitor object is shared by all Writer and Reader objects, I pass the same reference to a created monitor object as an argument to their constructors.

Comment: You suggest to put that logic at the end of startRead, but I want to do it using Start and End methods, could I then grab the lock at the beginning of startRead and release is at the end of endRead? Would it work the same way? Also, how could I make my readers to read just one int? If I just do `f.ReadInt()` without the while or setting the pointer to 0, exceptions are caught every time the reader tries to read.

Comment: If there is an int where you are pointing with seek then no exception should be thrown, as far as I understand. Not sure about locking at Start and unlocking at End, you could possibly create a method there that: locks, startRead, endRead, unlocks.

Comment: Now I am locking at the beginning of start (read or write) and unlocking at the end of end (read or write) and it seems to work. Exceptions were always thrown because the file pointer was at the end of the file, I had to do this f.seek(f.getFilePointer()-4); so it reads the last int written. But shouldn't this not be happening? Pointer should be positioned after the last int read, not always at the end of the file...

Comment: `while (f.getFilePointer()<f.length()) System.out.print(f.readInt()+" ");` This is quite sure to finish with pointer at the very end of the file. If you read a single int, then it would indeed move your pointer just "an int" forward, like you predicted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44327/discussion-between-byakuya-and-dabadaba)